# Chrome input and text area padding sucks

Tags: css, google-chrome, input, textarea

What the hell is that? I found there is some problem with padding in chrome with this elements but even if set the padding to 0 in both (textarea and input) they are not "looking same" width in chrome. The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!--[if IE]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
<title>WTF</title>
<style>
    input {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    textarea {
        width: 200px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    table {
    background-color: blue;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<form>
    <table>
    <tr><td><input type="text" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
<form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `border:0`, it fixes itself in chrome. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q96yN/2/

Comment: Actually I should add border: solid 1px black; to both. Cause these element are strange without border (if you dont have coloured background). But yes border was the problem, thx :)

Comment: @user1097772 No problem, and yes style-wise having a border would look **much much** nicer.

Comment: For everyone who would use this I advise set both to padding: 0px; border-width: 1px; border-style:inset; which is default style of text input in chrome and then it looks same and ok for me :) black border was too  
disruptive.